# blazor radzen dropdownDataGrid pagination problem

Tags: c#, pagination, blazor, dropdown, radzen

I added a pagination method to Radzen DropdownDataGrid as in the html file below, but it does not print the total page information and page numbers I received.

```
    <div>
        <RadzenDropDownDataGrid @bind-Value=@selectedItem @ref="companyGrid" Data=@companyModel?.data TextProperty="Name"
                                PagerAlwaysVisible="true" Count="@companyModel.totalCount" PageSize="@companyModel.pageSize" PageNumbersCount="2"
                        
                                ShowPagingSummary="true" PagingSummaryFormat="@pagingSummaryFormat">
        </RadzenDropDownDataGrid>
    </div>
```

Json - The json information I got is as follows

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "e1",
            "description": null,
            "createdBy": null,
            "updatedBy": null,
            "createdDate": null,
            "updatedDate": null
        },
        {
            "id": 11,
            "name": "e110",
            "description": null,
            "createdBy": null,
            "updatedBy": null,
            "createdDate": null,
            "updatedDate": null
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "e2",
            "description": null,
            "createdBy": null,
            "updatedBy": null,
            "createdDate": null,
            "updatedDate": null
        }
    ],
    "currentPage": 1,
    "totalPages": 4,
    "totalCount": 11,
    "pageSize": 3,
    "hasPreviousPage": false,
    "hasNextPage": true,
    "messages": null,
    "succeeded": true,
    "exception": null,
    "code": 0
}
```

[image]